# How to specify .so path to use with GDB whan analysing dump file?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries

I have a crash dump that I want to analyse with GDB on different computer. Crashed application uses several shared libraries (`*.so` files). I want GDB to load symbols from some of them **but I can't put all of them in the original path**.

Adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the environment doesn't help when working with dumps. When I type `info shared` it shows full (non-relative) paths:

```
(gdb) info shared
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007fad4fb7f220  0x00007fad4fb80179  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
...
                                        No          /opt/app/libXXX.so
...
```

How to specify different path for the example `libXXX.so` (from gdb command line or command prompt)?

Answer (score 0):

The `set solib-search-path` option is for that purpose. Documentation says it is ment for using with `gdbserver` but also works with dump analysis. By default, it is set to `.`, so the directory that `gdb` is run from.

**BUT:** for some reason it doesn't work out of the box (at least with gdb 10.2). I don't know the reason, but I know a workaround: just type `set solib-search-path .` as a first command after entering gdb prompt. The output is following for me:

```
(gdb) set solib-search-path .
Reading symbols from /home/example/path/libXXX.so...
```

Of course one can type any path she want instead of `.`.